# Problems with Networkx optimal_edit_paths (graph edit distance)

Tags: python, networkx

I'm using Networkx to find the graph edit distance (GED) between two directed acyclic graphs (DAGs) via the `Reconcile` method shown below, for the purpose of tree reconciliation. I map nodes and edges by their labels, which are (as shown) just their IDs.

In the test case below, I copy a graph `g1` to `g2` and add `n` new nodes/edges to `g2` then remove `m` nodes/edges. Even in the case of `n` = several hundred, the `Reconcile` method is very fast when `m` = 0. However, my problem is that it becomes very slow if I remove more than 2 or 3 nodes that would otherwise be common to both graphs.

```
import networkx as nx

class MyGraph(nx.DiGraph):

    @classmethod
    def Reconcile(cls, a1, a2):

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # STAGE 1: MAP NODES/EDGES B/T THE TWO GRAPHSS

    # Equality here means having same labels

        def return_eq(item1, item2):

            label1 = item1['label']
            label2 = item2['label']

            _eq = label1 == label2

            if _eq:
                print('Mapped ', label1, 'to ', label2)

            return _eq


        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        # STAGE 2: FIND EDIT PATHS

        paths, cost_nx = nx.optimal_edit_paths(a1, a2, node_match = return_eq, edge_match = return_eq)
        paths = paths[0]

        node_edits = [el for el in paths[0] if el[0] != el[1]]
        edge_edits = [el for el in paths[1] if el[0] != el[1]]
        cost = len(node_edits) + len(edge_edits)

        print('Node edits: {}\nEdge edits: {}\nTotal cost (Networkx): {}\nTotal cost (no. of edits): {}'.format(
            node_edits, edge_edits, cost_nx, cost))
        print('No. of node edits: ', len(node_edits))
        print('No. of edge edits: ', len(edge_edits))

        return paths, cost_nx, cost, node_edits, edge_edits

#######################################################

g1 = MyGraph()

p = 10
edges = [('root', edge) for edge in range(p)]
g1.add_edges_from(edges) # Add root and some nodes + edges

g2 = g1.copy()

n = 10
for edge in range(n):
    node = 100*(edge+10)
    print('Edge added: ', edge)
    g2.add_edge('root2', node) # Add some more edges + nodes not present in g1

m = 2 # When m > 2, code slows massively
for node in list(g1.nodes)[-m:]: # Any will do!
    print('Node/edge removed:', node)
    g2.remove_node(node)

for g in [g1,g2]:
    for node in g.nodes:
        g.nodes[node]['label'] = node
    for edge in g.edges:
        g.edges[edge]['label'] = edge

paths, cost_nx, cost, node_edits, edge_edits = MyGraph.Reconcile(g1,g2)
```

I may be missing something here, and it may be that the problem is simply a computational one: I realise it's a hard problem and I'm absolutely not suggesting there's a bug in Networkx. However, any help or insight would be much appreciated, for example by preconditioning the graphs in some way before attemping to reconcile them.